# Data is not displaying using Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am doing unit testing for the following `react` component:

```js
var userData=null;
class Login extends React.Component 
{
    getData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: myURL,
            success: function(data) {
               console.log(data);
               userData=data;
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("ERROR");
            }
        });
        console.log(userData);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            //some stuff
        );
    }
}
export default Login;
```

My test file code:

```js
test("Data should load",()=>{
  const wrapper = mount(<Login/>);
  const instance = wrapper.instance();
  instance.getData();
})
```

When I run this test file using `npm run test`, `userData is` coming as `null` and success function of ajax is not executing.
Where I did mistake?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to refactor your code a few so that it can be tested easier. Here is my solution:

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

var userData = null;
const myURL = 'http://stackoverflow.com';

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSuccess = this.handleSuccess.bind(this);
    this.handleError = this.handleError.bind(this);
  }
  getData() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: myURL,
      success: this.handleSuccess,
      error: this.handleError
    });
  }

  handleError() {
    console.log('ERROR');
  }

  handleSuccess(data) {
    userData = data;
    console.log(userData);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>some stuff</div>;
  }
}
export default Login;
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Login from './';

describe('Login', () => {
  let wrapper;
  let instance;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Login />);
    instance = wrapper.instance() as any;
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('Data should load', () => {
    const ajaxSpy = jest.spyOn($, 'ajax');
    expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('some stuff');
    instance.getData();
    expect(ajaxSpy).toBeCalledWith({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://stackoverflow.com',
      success: expect.any(Function),
      error: expect.any(Function)
    });
  });

  test('should handle success', () => {
    const mUser = { userId: 1 };
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    instance.handleSuccess(mUser);
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith(mUser);
  });

  test('should handle error', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    instance.handleError();
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('ERROR');
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58489318/index.spec.tsx (9.924s)
  Login
    ✓ Data should load (131ms)
    ✓ should handle success (17ms)
    ✓ should handle error (2ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    { userId: 1 }

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    ERROR

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.59s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58489318

Comment: If I don't know the data in handleSuccess then how to call handleSuccess?

Comment: @PavanPakki You need to know the data and write some business logic code and unit test for it. Otherwise, how to you write the business logic for `handleSuccess`? If you don't know the business logic, how do you test? The data you request should be found in an API doc